# Find user location (Please help me fix below or suggest any other way)

Tags: coldfusion, ip-geolocation, userlocation, showuserlocation

Hopefully, some one can help me with this issue. I am trying to implement a global site and hence was looking for a way to detect user location. I do not want to use any ip2location webservice or download a database or ask for user to "share location".

Anyways, I found this project. I implemented it , it detects my location correctly (US). However for my friend in Germany it is returning an empty string for Country.

http://javainetlocator.sourceforge.net/. I am using jar file from here.

I am using CF 11 and my code is on

http://roomdu.com/geolocator/

PLEASE SUGGEST ME

Comment: Are you aware that the same issue exists for the demo link provided on the sourceforge page you provided?http://www.sustainablegis.com/projects/geoLocator/  In other words, it's not your implementation, it's the vendor code that is the problem.

Comment: you'd be better off using a service like MaxMinds GeoIP service, which you can either buy or use their free version: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/ reading through the sourceforge link, it looks like it's using a vague hardcoded version of maxmind anyway, so using a DB would mean the data is more upto date

Comment: Hi All, 

Thanks for your quick responses. Yes, It make sense. Its a problem with the " InetAddressLocator". However what do you think will be best way to achieve. I am not fully convinced with database or webserivce due to performance reasons. 

Any one had experience in past?

Comment: what performance reasons are you having issue with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some German IPs are not in the IP database provided with InetAddressLocator.  You can see this by running it in interactive mode via command line.

> Codemans-MacBook:ColdFusionMX-geoLocator-2.23 Codeman$ java -jar InetAddressLocator.jar
>
> ```
>   InetAddressLocator - Java country lookup.
>   -----------------------------------------
>   Copyright (C) 2003-05 Nigel Wetters Gourlay and Paul Hastings
>   InetAddressLocator comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
>   This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute
>   it under the GNU General Public License.
>
>   Running benchmark. Please be patient...
>     Speed: 1260307 ops/sec
>            (61% of address space is allocated)
>
>   Locating localhost
>     Host: /192.168.15.238
>     Country: Unknown (private network)
>
>   enter host ('q' to quit) > 5.199.139.54
>     Host: /5.199.139.54
>     Country: Unknown
> ```

Comment: Hi All, 

Thanks for your quick responses. Yes, It make sense. Its a problem with the " InetAddressLocator". However what do you think will be best way to achieve. I am not fully convinced with database or webserivce due to performance reasons. 

Any one had experience in past?